# Storage requirements for couchdb or mongodb/cassandra or other nosql

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, couchdb, storage, nosql

I am trying to store data to retrieve it often and update from time to time (infrequently). It's mostly retrieval based on keys in a given format using a list.

I tried couchDB with 1G of raw json data and it works well but requires 8G of memory in couchDB !

I have the following json formatted data:

```
{"_id": "002100094112000000", ...mydata here}
```

Am I missing something ? Why does it balloon to 8G with couchdb ? Should I be using another system (cassandra, mongodb) ?

Comment: How complex is the data that you're retrieving? Is it simply a key-value store? If so, check out memcached.

Comment: yeah sort of, it's just the value is a set of strings with different values. I want 1) upload data in certain format 2) retrieve data in the same format but according to the numerical keys where I can do range queries (startkey-endkey). 3) do periodical updates

Comment: Do you have any views defined?  And are those views emitting the documents themselves?

Comment: Memcached will dump data if memory gets low.  Try MemBase or Redis if you need memcached key-value features with persistence.

Comment: MongoDB is very aggresive with disk space and would probably take more space than couchdb but it is so that it does not have to go through the procedure of allocating space on the spot which takes longer. It does reuse old space and normally the db isn't actually taking up that amount of space it is just the pre-allocation files that are.

Comment: Cassandra would do better because it includes transparent compression, which helps a lot (https://twitter.com/rbranson/status/215681181050613760).  That said, modeling as One Big Key is discouraged in Cassandra; see www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1